# optimize mysql indexes

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a slow (1.4 second) query that has been bugging me for a while so I just thought I'd put it up and see if anyone can help me optimize my indexes to speed it up:

```
select sql_calc_found_rows t.id, q.im_id, concat(t.si_id, ' ', t.de), q.date, q.das, q.dac, u.name, q.ac, q.st
from t300q q
left join t300 t on t.id = q.con_id
left join users u on u.id = q.user_id
order by q.date desc limit 0,100
```

sql explain results:

```
SIMPLE q ALL     89126 Using filesort
SIMPLE t eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 db.q.con_id 1
SIMPLE u eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 db.q.user_id 1
```

session stats:

```
Handler_read_first = 0
Handler_read_key = 177934
Handler_read_next = 23
Handler_read_prev = 679
Handler_read_rnd = 15
Handler_read_rnd_next = 89127
```

and I have the following indexes:

```
t.id - primary key

q.con_id    |
q.date      | - all form a single index
q.user_id   |

u.id - primary key
```

as you can see from the handler stats the size of table `q` is 89126 rows.

It's not a massive problem but I would like to get the speed down below 1 second for this query if possible.

Comment: `q.date` should have index? http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: Totally not answering your question, but do you have the option of trying the same query under PostgreSQL? I can usually get 10-table joins with 10s of millions of rows each down to a few hundred milliseconds. It's great about combining indexes on its own when needed.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have postgresql

Answer (score 1):

The query is slow because you don't have a date index.  The compound index cannot be used because the date is in the middle.  Either move the date to be the first field in the existing index or create a stand alone index.

Comment: i tried moving the date to the first position in the index but the query still takes 1.4 seconds, then i tried adding a new index for q.date by itself (and leaving the other index with q.date, q.con_id, q.user_id) but the query is still taking about 1.4 seconds. thanks for your ideas though

Comment: how long the query takes is irrelevant for troubleshooting.  What's important is whether there were any changes to the execution plan.  Where there?

Comment: good point. there are no changes to the `explain select` output with any of these three key definitions. however i just tried exactly the same thing on another development database that uses a later version of mysql and the query is executing in 0.4 seconds so it must just be that...

Answer (score 1):

BTW mysql uses only equality for the first two columns of a 3 column index.  The last column can use ranged queries.

Namely:

```
WHERE x=? AND y=? order by z;
```

will use an index of columns (x,y,z) (since z can be ranged).

Try moving 'date' to the 3rd column and rewriting the query.

If that doesn't work, then mysql isn't being smart enough to treat con_id and user_id in the join.. Perhaps you could rewrite it so those join conditions happen in the where clause.

Comment: ok i tried restoring just a single index consisting of the following fields in this order: q.con_id, q.user_id, q.date, but the speed remains around 1.4 seconds :P not sure about re-writing the query - i'll keep that as a last resort since it sounds like bad sql practise. thanks for the tips anyhow

Answer (score 0):

try to trigger the OPTIMIZE or ANALYZE on your database but make sure that you trigger this on the time on which there are only few request or much better if there are no request that are being done on the server to avoid any problems to arise you may see more informations about this statements on this links:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/optimize-table.html